# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mqtt_test'

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

I have installed both commands still getting this error.
pip install mqtt
pip install paho-mqtt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mqtt_test'
[image: My Code]
[image: Error]

I was expecting to run my Django App fine.

Comment: Please do not post images of text, they are hard to read, and impossible to search or for users of screen readers. Post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it.

Answer (score 0):

Module not found error only occurs when the module is not installed. If the module is available on [PyPi](https://pypi.org), then run `pip install mqtt_test` on your `cmd`. Elsewise, you can manually install the module by checking their docs.

You could also check this out: https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt.

Comment: by running this command I am getting error
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mqtt_test (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mqtt_test

Comment: if you find any material to install it manually please share

Comment: Could you tell me what does this module do and functions. Here's something I found: https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/. Not sure if this is it. Let me know if you get any information about the module.

Comment: yeah this is exact module.